Equivalent characterizations of a discrete variable
A discrete random variable is usually defined as that which has a countable image. I suspect (though have failed at proving) the following:
Theorem: for a random variable $X$ with cdf $F$, the following are equivalent:

$\text{im}(X)$ is countable.
There exists a function $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ F(x) = \sum_{y\le x}p(x).$$
$F$ is a step (simple) function i.e. there are constants $\{c_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and sets $\{E_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such tht
$$F(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty{c_k}1_{E_k}(x).$$

I have only been able to show $(1\implies 2)$. Is the theorem correct? If so, how could it be proven? If not, what is a counterexample?

Might be related.

How do you define $im(X)$? For a literal interpretation of $\im$, 1 and 2 are obviously not equivalent. But if you use the support of $P_X$ instead of $\im(x)$, then 1 and 2 are equivalent

What do you mean by a "simple" function?

@DaigakunoBaku I edited the post to (hopefully) answer that.

@Kakashi I do defined it literally. Why are $(1)$ and $(2)$ not equivalent?

Take $X$ to be the identitfy function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $X$ have PMF $p(x) = 2^{-x}I(x \in \mathbb{N})$. Then $im(X) = {X(\omega) : \omega \in \mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}$, while the support of $P_X$ is $\mathbb{N}$.

@Kakashi Sorry, but what is $I$? and could you help me see how $p$ can be a pmf of $X$? What probability measure would you use for this?

@Kakashi in fact, should we not have that $\text{im}(X)$ is countable if and only if $\text{im}(p)$ ($p$ being the the pmf of $X$) is countable?

Let $p$ be any PMF on $\mathbb{Z}$. The formal specification is to consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$ where $\mu = \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}}p(x)\delta_x$. Then the identity function $X$ has distribution $P_X = \mu$ that has the PMF $p(x) = P(X = x)$.

The real definition of discreteness is that a Borel probability measure $\mu$ is discrete if it's support, the smallest closed set $F$ for which $\mu(F) = 1$, is a countable or finite set.

"closed support" isn't the right thing to use here. If $\mu$ is concentrated on the rationals and gives positive weight to each one, then the closed support of $\mu$ is $\Bbb R$.
A better way to capture discreteness is to say that there is a countable set $K$ such that $\mu(K)=1$. This, as a replacement for 1. is equivalent to 2. and to 3.

@JohnDawkins could you point me to a proof of that?

You could have a look at Resnick's "A Probability Path" or Kai Lai Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory".
